# Import CSV to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Wizard

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I have a very simple (but big) `CSV` file and I want to import it to my database in *Microsoft SQL Server 2014* (Database/Tasks/Import Data). But I receive the following `error` :

> The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data".

Here is a sample of my `CSV` file (containing ~ 9 million rows) :

```
1393013,297884,'20150414 15:46:25'
1393010,301242,'20150414 15:46:58'
```

Ideally my first and second columns are big-int and the third is `datetime`. In the wizard, I choose 'unsigned 8 byte integer' for first two and `'timestamp'` for the third and I receive the error. Even I try to use string for all three columns as data type and still I receive the same error.

I also tried using `bcp` command in command line. It errs nothing and inserts nothing! Also using `"bulk insert"` command errors me that :

```
the column is too long! verify your terminators
```

But they are correctly fixed!

I appreciate any idea you have as a solution to this simple-looking problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the input types: unsigned 8 byte integer is a setting on the source.
You don't need to change source setting at all. 'string [DT_STR]' and the default length of 50 will work.

'timestamp' is a binary type. I believe the type you are after is datetime, but that set is on the destination, not the source. The source is still a string regardless.

You still will not be able to import your date value as a datetime data type.
This would work though (added dashes) -> 2015-04-14 15:46:25. Import what you have as string and fix it after import unless you can get your text file changed.